# Is it possible to use the new 2010 Calendar Overlays before running the Visual Upgrade?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Preface:
I have a rolling upgrade to SharePoint 2010 in progress for one of our clients. Their content has been upgraded to 2010, but they remain on the old visual style; their site has not applied the visual upgrade. We're trying to ease them into the new interface piece by piece since some of our custom code also needs to be updated to accomodate the new visual layout.

Question:
Is there a way we can use Calendar Overlays in 2010 before we run the Visual Upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can only use the new Calendar, complete with overlays, after you have run the Visual Upgrade.

Comment: When I tried the V4 URLs on the V3 Site (by harvesting the V4 URLs and changing the Site and List ID's), it seems it *could* be done. That is, SharePoint didn't through an error when I visited the screen.